# Selecting a material from a list, storing it and then returning the material as a new mater

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to C# and trying to produce a script in Unity that takes a list of meshes and materials then, via input searches through the items in the list and picks out the one with the same input.
Taking the outputted new mesh and storing it in a new material/mesh.
The idea behind this is to take the isolated Meshes and Materials to create a dictionary that means certain meshes will only use certain materials based on their naming conventions.

I have managed to do so with the meshes, they return the object as a new mesh.

However, the materials on the other hand, even though they're following the same logic are outputting the error "error CS1729: 'Material' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Can anyone suggest a solution as I have be rattling my head and searching for days trying to find a solution.

I have looked all over and I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem, I have a feeling that it'll be rather simple.
I have looked over many documents and read through the unity documentation but nothing is making sense to me.

Edit: I am using Universal Render Pipeline/Toon shaders

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Diagnostics;


public class CharacterCreationMaster : MonoBehaviour
{


    //reference for unity to check
    [Header("Meshes to change")]
    public List<MeshFilter> changeMesh = new List<MeshFilter>();

    //Drag all of the objects that you need edit 
    [Header("Meshes to cycle through")]
    public List<Mesh> meshOptions = new List<Mesh>();

    //all the materials that you need to edit
    [Header("Materials to cycle through")]
    public List<Material> materialOptions = new List<Material>();


    Material materialIsolator(string input)
    {

        Material peephairMat;

        //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Hello");
        for (int i = 0; i < materialOptions.Count; i++)
        {
            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("We are printing the name of the material. " + materialOptions[i].name);
            if (string.Compare(materialOptions[i].name, input) == 0)
            {
                peephairMat = materialOptions[i];
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("we have selected " + materialOptions[i]);
                return peephairMat;
            }
        }
        return new Material();

    }


    Mesh meshIsolator(string input)
    {

        Mesh peepHair;

        //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Hello");
        for (int i = 0; i < meshOptions.Count; i++)
        {
            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log(meshOptions[i].name);
            if (string.Compare(meshOptions[i].name, input) == 0)
            {
                peepHair = meshOptions[i];
                //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("we have selected " + meshOptions[i]);
                return peepHair;
            }
        }

        //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("We have created a new mesh.");
        return new Mesh();

    }


    void Start()
    {

        Mesh finsHair = meshIsolator("fin-Hair");
        Mesh quinsHair = meshIsolator("quin-Hair");
        Mesh nailsHair = meshIsolator("nail-Hair");


        //Material quin1HairMats = materialIsolator("Quin1_Hair");
        //Material quin2HairMats = materialIsolator("Quin2_Hair");
        //Material quin3HairMats = materialIsolator("Quin3_Hair");

    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-ctor.html see the reference here - creating a new `Material` requires you to pass either a `Shader` instance or an existing `Material` instance - there is no constructor that accepts 0 arguments. It sounds like you probably want to clone an existing material?

Comment: Yes, the material that is in the value of the material list that holds the same value as the input.

I am wanting to clone that material but unsure of how exactly that is going to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding - you are searching a material list for a material which matches the `input` value, you then return that very same material (not a clone). Only when you don't find the material do you attempt to return a new material. What is supposed to happen when you a: do find a matching material b: do not find a matching material?

Comment: When you find the matching material I am wanting to return that as a new material so that I can use that new material as a value for a key and value pair in a dictionary.
If a material is not found I am not wanting the script to do anything, or rather I want it to cease.

Comment: Ok so return `null` as the value instead. For the matching material, return a clone if you really need a clone or just return the existing material (I can't see how you are using this script, so I can't comment on whether you need a clone or not). `return null` at the bottom of the function will return a null object which doesn't represent any `Material` - you can then check if the return value is null when calling this function and decide what to do based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'd propose a few small tweaks - I assume you are using this as an editor panel or something?

```
    Material materialIsolator(string input)
    {
        // First of all, you can use a foreach or Linq here to grab a matching instance
        // Looping over arrays using a for loop is not required when using List<T> types
        // so either...
        foreach(var material in materialOptions) 
        {
            if (material.name == input) {
                // Do you actually need a new material or just a ref to the existing material?
                return new Material(material);
        }

        // return null if nothing can be found with this name
        return null;
    }
```

Or just use LINQ:

```
    Material materialIsolator(string input)
    {
        return materialOptions.FirstOrDefault(material => material.name == input);
    }

    // which actually means you don't need the function in the first place and can just use

    Mesh nailsHair = materialOptions.FirstOrDefault(material => material.name == 'nail-Hair');
```

The only question is, do you need a new material or a ref to the original material, in which case you just need to wrap the returned object with `new Material(<object here>)`

Comment: So I have gone with the return null; option.

This is primarily just because I am not needing to do anything with the material once I have isolated it, I just need to isolate it to then apply it to a dictionary. For this it has worked and I can now progress with the project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:

```
return new Material();
```

Material requires a shader to be passed to the constructor. So you will either have to return an existing Material as default, or pass a shader to the constructor.